# drawImage not displaying whole image?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am trying to draw an image to a JPanel which in turn is added to a JFrame, see here:

```
JFrame screen;

public void welcome(){  
      screen = new JFrame("Welcome");
      screen.setVisible(true);
      screen.pack();
      screen.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
      screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
}

// in the original code there is series of methods here that eventually calls the drawBoard() method

public void drawBoard(){
try {
     final BufferedImage gboard = ImageIO.read(new File("cutsomGameBoard.jpg"));
     final BufferedImage featPanel = ImageIO.read(new File("extraPanel.png"));
     board = new JPanel(){
         protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(gboard, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };
    extra = new JPanel(){
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(featPanel, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };

        board.setSize(480, 480);
        extra.setSize(480, 320);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

   gameScreen.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
   gameScreen.add(board, BorderLayout.EAST);
   gameScreen.add(extra, BorderLayout.WEST);
   gameScreen.setVisible(true);
   screen.add(gameScreen);
}
```

My problem is that when running the code, only a small corner of the buffered image is visible and I am not sure if it is a problem with the frame layout, the panel size or the drawImage method arguments, ideas?

P.S. The output: screenshot of java window

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkrWF.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom component so the default size is basically (10, 10) which is the size of a panel using a FlowLayout with no added components.

Don't use a JPanel to display an image. Or if you do want to use a JPanel then you need to implement the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of your image.

The easiest solution is to just use a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more information and working examples.